# How are character values interpreted by between operators? (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, character, between

I had a code in SQL which passes for

```
'2:00' between '10:00' and '22:00'
```

but fails for

```
'02:00' between '10:00' and '22:00'
```

Can anyone help me understand how string values are interpreted by between operators and how the above given scenario has occurred?

Comment: Input and expected output?

Comment: Are the above meant to be times? If so, you should really be using the `time` data type and not relying on string "ordering"

Comment: Yes, I ended up casting it to time, but still curious as to how it works with Strings

Answer (score 3):

In your first `BETWEEN` clause, which passes erroneously:

```
'2:00' between '10:00' and '22:00'
```

The values are sorting lexicographically as *text*, not as numbers.  Here they are sorted as text:

```
10:00
2:00
22:00
```

The text `22` is "greater" than `2:`, so the check passes.  The solution here is either to compare the times as numbers, or always ensure that the times have the same width.  Assuming your data look like the first case, you may try casting to time in SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE CAST('2:00' AS time) BETWEEN '10:00' AND '22:00';
```

The above query will fail, as expected, because you are now comparing a proper time literal against a range of proper time literals.

Comment: But `SELECT CASE WHEN '2:00' between '10:00' and '22:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` returns `1` not `0`.

Comment: @Larnu On a cell phone right now, got 3 hours of sleep last night staying up to watch a newborn baby (while also answering Stack Overflow questions).

Comment: Check the query at the end of my answer, which fails with the cast, but passes without it.

Comment: Ahh, I see, I have miss read your logic, apologies. Think it was initial ordering that threw me; you are indeed correct.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Forgive my ignorance. I still dont understand how the text '22' is greater than '2:'

Comment: It has to do with how your time values are sorting as text.  Use the query at the end of my answer to convince you of this.

Comment: @Abirami, the first character of both values( '2') is equal and the second character ':' is less than '2'.  Consequently '2:00' is less than '22:00'. Use proper data types and you'll get the expected comparison semantics.

Comment: @Dan Can you explain why `2` is greater than `:` here, given that the order in the ASCII table is the opposite of this?

Comment: That's to do with collations, rather than the Ascii values, @TimBiegeleisen .

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen with a dictionary order collation (e.g. `Latin1_General_CI_AS`), SQL Server compares as I mentioned: `SELECT '>' WHERE '2'  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS > ':' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;`. Although not commonly used, a binary collation will use the code points: `SELECT '<' WHERE '2'  COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN > ':' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;`

Comment: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dba3cd41e57c7a07c8b2c234fb267f1e) showing differences of order between `Latin1_General_CI_AI` and `Latin1_General_BIN`

Comment: Thanks to both of you, the real SQL Server gurus `:-)`